# How to get a compact letter display from a matrix of p-values?

Tags: r, matrix, data-visualization

Consider this data, where we have several groups with 10 observations each, and we conduct a `pairwise.t.test()`:

```r
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:18], each = 10),
                   var = rnorm(180, mean = 2, sd = 5))
ttres <- pairwise.t.test(x=data$var, g=data$group, p.adjust.method = "none")#just to make sure i get some sigs for the example
```

You can return a matrix of p values from this test like this:

```r
pmat <- as.matrix(ttres$p.value)
```

With the results in the shape of a correlation matrix like this, how can we get a compact letter display from the results? By this I mean I am looking to get output in the form of letters that show which groups are different, and which groups are not. By this I mean that I am looking to produce what the `cld` function from the `multcomp` package does for a tukeys test: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/multcomp/versions/1.4-13/topics/cld, which illustrates which groups are different, and which groups are not.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: @akrun just a list of letters from a compact letter display showing which groups are different based on a 0.05 alpha level. is this what you meant by expected output? If so I will clarify in the question

Comment: Do you need `subset(as.data.frame.table(pmat) , !is.na(Freq) & Freq < 0.05)` or perhaps `which(pmat < 0.05, arr.ind = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functions `fullPTable()` and `multcompLetters()`, found in the `library(rcompanion)` and `library(multcompView)`.

Here is how I would solve your problem:

```
library(rcompanion)
library(multcompView)
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(group = rep(letters[1:18], each = 10),
                   var = rnorm(180, mean = 2, sd = 5))

PT <- pairwise.t.test(x=data$var, g=data$group, p.adjust.method = "none")#just to make sure i get some sigs for the example
PT = PT$p.value
PT1 = fullPTable(PT)
multcompLetters(PT1,
                compare="<",
                threshold=0.05,
                Letters=letters,
                reversed = FALSE)
```